# How to mock an object while python testing with PyTest?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

During testing I need to mock an object. I am currently using Pytest and monkeypatch for mocking.

example function:

```
def isGccInstalled():
    gccInstallationFound = False
    command = ['gcc', '-v']
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, 
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    if process.stdout.readline:
        gccInstallationFound = True        
    return gccInstallationFound
```

My test for the function:

```
def mock_subprocess_Popen(*args, **kwargs):
    return

def test_getSwBlockType(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(subprocess, "Popen", mock_subprocess_Popen)
    assert isGccInstalled() == "False"
```

I need to somehow mock the process object and write my own string into process.stdout.readline.
I am aware that I can mock single variables using monkeypatch.setattr, but I don't know how to mock objects or even objects that inherit from other classes. Is there a way to tell my mock to return a dummy data structure with a "process.stdout.readline" accessible?

Comment: `i can mock single variables using monkeypatch.setattr, but i don't know how to mock objects` - in Python, we have duck typing. As long as the thing has methods you want to use, you can use it in that context. So you basically need to return something that has `.stdout` attribute and that stdout has `.readline` attribute.

Comment: Did you look into unittest.mock? https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: so the only way would be to create a fake stdout class that contains an object of another fake class readline?